# How to update form fields

Tags: c#, forms, nopcommerce

I have an address form. I want to edit the form field values after submit.How to do that by ajax call or can i change the form fields by controller?
In controller they're getting form values from IFormCollection which provides read only variables to access value?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow !. Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the IFormCollection at the controller side. Bellow code exist at AddProductToCart_Details Method of ShoppingCart Controller. You will see this type to other controller's method.

```
  foreach (var formKey in form.Keys)
            if (formKey.Equals($"addtocart_{productId}.EnteredQuantity", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                int.TryParse(form[formKey], out quantity);
                break;
            }
```